# Linux - What should I consider as my disk space usage (apparent size or something else)?

Tags: linux, directory, size

I have a directory called `/tmp/kafka-logs` which I can see using `ncdu` or `du` command to find out my disk space usage.

1. I am using Fedora Doplphin GUI browser on my laptop.
2. When I see using my GUI file explorer, the directory size shows `1.0 GB`
3. When I use `du -sb /tmp/kafka-logs` - I can see the same as GUI
4. When I use `du -sh /tmp/kafka-logs` - I see something totally different - `20.0 M`

I came across [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173947/du-s-apparent-size-vs-du-s) answer in SO. If I understand correctly, this is also considered the size when the data is transferred over the wire to, perhaps, another computer.

So, my question is - "What is my directory size in terms of disk space usage"?

May be it's my lack of understanding, or may be I am checking the right thing, so any help is appreciated...

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su] or possible [unix.se]  , but please read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks - the question link on SO I posed also is Linux. So, the expectation is that someone might be able to help me here. I have now posed the same question on SU site.